# **Jenkins: Unable to upload files to aws S3 bucket**

Tags: jenkins, amazon-s3, jenkins-plugins

I am unable to upload the build artifacts to aws s3 bucket after building the code.

The below is the snippet of console output i got from jenkins.

> Created
>   /data/tomcat/jenkins/workspace/Test_job@tmp/.npmrc2357185941074023133Deleting
>   1 temporary files Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket Build is still
>   running Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket Using S3 profile:
>   newui-jenkins-user Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket
>   bucket=ri-newui-development/, file=0.js region=us-west-2, will be
>   uploaded from slave=false managed=true , server encryption true
>   Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket bucket=ri-newui-development/,
>   file=0.js.gz region=us-west-2, will be uploaded from slave=false
>   managed=true , server encryption true Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket
>   bucket=ri-newui-development/, file=0.js.map region=us-west-2, will be
>   uploaded from slave=false managed=true , server encryption true
>   Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket bucket=ri-newui-development/, file=1.js
>   region=us-west-2, will be uploaded from slave=false managed=true ,
>   server encryption true Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket
>   bucket=ri-newui-development/, file=1.js.gz region=us-west-2, will be
>   uploaded from slave=false managed=true , server encryption true
>   Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket bucket=ri-newui-development/,
>   file=1.js.map region=us-west-2, will be uploaded from slave=false
>   managed=true , server encryption true Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket
>   bucket=ri-newui-development/, file=2.js region=us-west-2, will be
>   uploaded from slave=false managed=true , server encryption true
>   Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket bucket=ri-newui-development/,
>   file=2.js.gz region=us-west-2, will be uploaded from slave=false
>   managed=true , server encryption true Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket
>   bucket=ri-newui-development/, file=2.js.map region=us-west-2, will be
>   uploaded from slave=false managed=true , server encryption true
>   Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket bucket=ri-newui-development/, file=3.js
>   region=us-west-2, will be uploaded from slave=false managed=true ,
>   server encryption true Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket
>   bucket=ri-newui-development/, file=3.js.gz region=us-west-2, will be
>   uploaded from slave=false managed=true , server encryption true
>   Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket bucket=ri-newui-development/,
>   file=3.js.map region=us-west-2, will be uploaded from slave=false
>   managed=true , server encryption true Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket
>   bucket=ri-newui-development/, file=4.js region=us-west-2, will be
>   uploaded from slave=false managed=true , server encryption true
>   Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket bucket=ri-newui-development/,
>   file=4.js.gz region=us-west-2, will be uploaded from slave=false
>   managed=true , server encryption true Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket
>   bucket=ri-newui-development/, file=4.js.map region=us-west-2, will be
>   uploaded from slave=false managed=true , server encryption true
>   Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket bucket=ri-newui-development/, file=5.js
>   region=us-west-2, will be uploaded from slave=false managed=true ,
>   server encryption true Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket
>   bucket=ri-newui-development/, file=5.js.gz region=us-west-2, will be
>   uploaded from slave=false managed=true , server encryption true
>   Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket bucket=ri-newui-development/,
>   file=5.js.map region=us-west-2, will be uploaded from slave=false
>   managed=true , server encryption true Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket
>   bucket=ri-newui-development/, file=6.js region=us-west-2, will be
>   uploaded from slave=false managed=true , server encryption true
>   Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket bucket=ri-newui-development/,
>   file=6.js.gz region=us-west-2, will be uploaded from slave=false
>   managed=true , server encryption true Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket
>   bucket=ri-newui-development/, file=6.js.map region=us-west-2, will be
>   uploaded from slave=false managed=true , server encryption true
>   Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket bucket=ri-newui-development/, file=7.js
>   region=us-west-2, will be uploaded from slave=false managed=true ,
>   server encryption true Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket
>   bucket=ri-newui-development/, file=7.js.gz region=us-west-2, will be
>   uploaded from slave=false managed=true , server encryption true
>   Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket bucket=ri-newui-development/,
>   file=7.js.map region=us-west-2, will be uploaded from slave=false
>   managed=true , server encryption true Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket
>   bucket=ri-newui-development/, file=8.js region=us-west-2, will be
>   uploaded from slave=false managed=true , server encryption true
>   Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket bucket=ri-newui-development/,
>   file=8.js.map region=us-west-2, will be uploaded from slave=false
>   managed=true , server encryption true Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket
>   bucket=ri-newui-development/, file=grid-search-internal.js
>   region=us-west-2, will be uploaded from slave=false managed=true ,
>   server encryption true Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket
>   bucket=ri-newui-development/, file=grid-search-internal.js.gz
>   region=us-west-2, will be uploaded from slave=false managed=true ,
>   server encryption true Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket
>   bucket=ri-newui-development/, file=grid-search-internal.js.map
>   region=us-west-2, will be uploaded from slave=false managed=true ,
>   server encryption true Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket
>   bucket=ri-newui-development/, file=index.html region=us-west-2, will
>   be uploaded from slave=false managed=true , server encryption true
>   Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket bucket=ri-newui-development/,
>   file=main.js region=us-west-2, will be uploaded from slave=false
>   managed=true , server encryption true Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket
>   bucket=ri-newui-development/, file=main.js.gz region=us-west-2, will
>   be uploaded from slave=false managed=true , server encryption true
>   Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket bucket=ri-newui-development/,
>   file=main.js.map region=us-west-2, will be uploaded from slave=false
>   managed=true , server encryption true Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket
>   bucket=ri-newui-development/, file=maintenance-internal.js
>   region=us-west-2, will be uploaded from slave=false managed=true ,
>   server encryption true Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket
>   bucket=ri-newui-development/, file=maintenance-internal.js.gz
>   region=us-west-2, will be uploaded from slave=false managed=true ,
>   server encryption true Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket
>   bucket=ri-newui-development/, file=maintenance-internal.js.map
>   region=us-west-2, will be uploaded from slave=false managed=true ,
>   server encryption true Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket
>   bucket=ri-newui-development/, file=polyfills.js region=us-west-2, will
>   be uploaded from slave=false managed=true , server encryption true
>   Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket bucket=ri-newui-development/,
>   file=polyfills.js.gz region=us-west-2, will be uploaded from
>   slave=false managed=true , server encryption true Publish artifacts to
>   S3 Bucket bucket=ri-newui-development/, file=polyfills.js.map
>   region=us-west-2, will be uploaded from slave=false managed=true ,
>   server encryption true Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket
>   bucket=ri-newui-development/, file=search-internal.js
>   region=us-west-2, will be uploaded from slave=false managed=true ,
>   server encryption true Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket
>   bucket=ri-newui-development/, file=search-internal.js.gz
>   region=us-west-2, will be uploaded from slave=false managed=true ,
>   server encryption true Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket
>   bucket=ri-newui-development/, file=search-internal.js.map
>   region=us-west-2, will be uploaded from slave=false managed=true ,
>   server encryption true Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket
>   bucket=ri-newui-development/, file=shared.js region=us-west-2, will be
>   uploaded from slave=false managed=true , server encryption true
>   Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket bucket=ri-newui-development/,
>   file=shared.js.gz region=us-west-2, will be uploaded from slave=false
>   managed=true , server encryption true Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket
>   bucket=ri-newui-development/, file=shared.js.map region=us-west-2,
>   will be uploaded from slave=false managed=true , server encryption
>   true Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket bucket=ri-newui-development/,
>   file=vendor.js region=us-west-2, will be uploaded from slave=false
>   managed=true , server encryption true Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket
>   bucket=ri-newui-development/, file=vendor.js.gz region=us-west-2, will
>   be uploaded from slave=false managed=true , server encryption true
>   Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket bucket=ri-newui-development/,
>   file=vendor.js.map region=us-west-2, will be uploaded from slave=false
>   managed=true , server encryption true
>
> ERROR: Failed to upload files
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The bucket is in
>   this region: null. Please use this region to retry the request
>   (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 301; Error Code: PermanentRedirect;
>   Request ID: EDD73B3CC84C0AF6), S3 Extended Request ID:
>   ONgTnwkLfl7piKKMBtueCrbpXYNVfbx8nTMve+/Gv+sSuFX4BAQY3ZuIR3rFrTPI0EJZnyBFquQ=
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1545)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1183)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:964)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:676)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:650)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:633)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$300(AmazonHttpClient.java:601)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:583)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:447)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4137)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1685)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadCallable.uploadInOneChunk(UploadCallable.java:133)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadCallable.call(UploadCallable.java:125)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadMonitor.call(UploadMonitor.java:139)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadMonitor.call(UploadMonitor.java:47)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Build step 'Publish artifacts to S3 Bucket' changed build result to
>   UNSTABLE Finished: UNSTABLE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've faced this problem when my default region was different from the region the bucket was in. Changing the default region to the region the bucket is in will solve this problem.

Can you verify what your AWS_DEFAULT_REGION is set to or what is your default region in ~/.aws/config and what region the bucket is in?

Comment: Sure. thanks much for you help. i will check that out and revert back to you.  So other than this do i need to change any configurations in Jenkins ?

Comment: This Solved my problem. Thanks @colwin